# changing css3 animation iteration count from infinite does nothing

Tags: animation, css

I have a css3 animation running with the iteration count set to infinite.

based on a click event I want to stop the animation but changing the iteration count does nothing.  can anyone suggest a better solution?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your animation in a class sepeared from the styling, i.e.

```
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.box.animated {
  -webkit-animation... 
}
```

and then remove class animated on click.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  It turned out this solution worked great and is now being implemented.  Thanks for your answer.